# HP G7 bluetooth not detected at all

Tags: drivers, bluetooth

I have this HP G7-1260CA that doesn't detect the bluetooth adapter I put in it.

I've purchased a WIFI card from HP, that is a combo wifi-bluetooth card, model BCM94313HMGB

The Broadcom BCM94313HMGB is a mini PCI-E card made up from a BCM2070 bluetooth module and a BCM4313 WLAN module.

I've tried installing the broadcom bluetooth software from http://www.broadcom.com/support/bluetooth/update.php but it says no bluetooth card is found. I've also tried installing the BCM2070 drivers found on hp's site for another model, no dice.

I've found out that wireless connections are managed by HP connection manager on this model. Installed it, it doesn't talk about bluetooth, just wifi and wired connection.

Am i missing something here ? Wireless switch on the laptop is on, the wifi portion of the card works.

Here's a pic of the card :  img.inkfrog.com/click_enlarge1.php?image=DF2403.jpg&username=montrealappletech&aid=800123462

That's what i have, on the card you see a BT MAC: so there's def. a bluetooth portion on the card !

I was wondering if the HP connection manager i've downloaded from the laptop's support page had the bluetooth portion ripped out because the laptop didn't come with BT.. But that would be odd

Anyone has a clue on this one ? Thanks a lot !!!

I'm installing bluetooth on this laptop because it has a fried USB controller, and need an external mouse.

EDIT ; From the G7 maintenance and service guide, http://h10032.www1.hp.com/ctg/Manual/c02834058.pdf

It seems this card i have installed is in the whitelist. Why isn't it working?

Comment: the image link says access denied upload it to http://imgur.com/

Answer (score 0):

- have a look in device manager (Logo key) + (Pause Key) = shortcut
- If missing install drivers from manufacturers page or using driver pack

Comment: Nope, nothing's even detected at all in the device manager !

Comment: the circuits might be burned.. Try another card

Comment: I tried another one, identical one. Same result !

Comment: circuits is messed up buy another laptop or motherboard for replacement.. or try with port converters Homer 0ut

Comment: Not really useful is it ?

Comment: go to http://www.ammyy.com and download it give me your id nr as well for remote support

Comment: 21 595 930 is the id

Comment: Ok am connecting now

Comment: You have to accept connection

Comment: Remember to close ammyy and do not accept any more connection from anyone link to usb board http://www.ebay.co.uk/itm/Hp-G61-420ca-USB-Board-And-Cable-/120993902902?pt=UK_Computing_Other_Computing_Networking&hash=item1c2bcc7136

Comment: i don't need to fix the usb, i need to fix the bluetooth that's on the mini-pci-e card :/ thanks for the help, though

Comment: Try updating PCI-e drivers could not find your model nr in hp,s website go to device manager and find ven and dev id and have a look here http://pcidatabase.com/ then download and install drivers if that does not work try replacing pci-e board if not build into motherboard And check if bluetooth device gives any light when connecting it

Comment: it's not detected !! :)

Comment: - ammyy stoped working on me so i could not check a few things. does your laptop have a wireless card already? | How many PCI slots does it exist | Are you sure you have installed the correct drivers for your device else remove the old ones and install this http://drivers.softpedia.com/get/NETWORK-CARD/OTHER-NETWORK-CARDS/Broadcom-BCM-943xx-Driver-4102284.shtml | Try running live linux distro example http://slax.org on usb or cd does it find bluetooth device?

Comment: i found out. i tried the MINI-pci-e card in another laptop, bluetooth was working. checking device manager, it seems the bluetooth card is somehow linked to the usb detection of devices.. so on the g7, the USB controller that is fried is the culprit. I tried hard on this one to get a mouse working, but it seems im stuck !

Comment: I'll connect again tonight using other remote software then ammyy and we will sort it out :)

Comment: Hi Cheebster well try with Teamviewer today Site:www.teamviewer.com send the id + password to sm92mual@hotmail.com  //Homer

Comment: No, no, there's nothing you can do about it, it's hardware !

Answer (score 0):

According to the [service manual for the HP Pavilion G6 Notebook](http://www.hp.com/ctg/Manual/c02770249.pdf), there's an additional "Bluetooth Cable" ([HP Part #602822-001](http://partsurfer.hp.com/ShowPhoto.aspx?partnumber=602822-001)) that will also need to be installed to get BT functioning.

Comment: My bad. I made a typo when i posted. It's an HP G7 !

Answer (score 0):

This card is pure crap. I have the same one and I spent the last two hours trying to make it work on my Dell Latitude E6400.

This card is actually two distinct parts glued together, one is a standard PCI Wi-Fi card that works fine, the second is a BCM92070 which is a USB Bluetooth module and it is attached to the USB lines of the mini PCI-Express port.

The USB module requires a firmware to be loaded before it can be used, and it seems like any communication with it before that firmware is loaded can brick it and make it unusable until the next shutdown (a reboot won't do, it needs to be completely unpowered for a few seconds).

The BIOS of my computer was apparently attempting to communicate with it before the OS had a chance to load its firmware, and that was bricking it - it then appeared to the OS as an unknown device (hardware ID says `USB/UNKNOWN`) with USB PID (product ID) 0000 and VID (vendor ID) 0000.

I fixed it on my machine by disabling "Bluetooth device" in the wireless devices tab in the BIOS - that tells the BIOS to ignore (but not disable - given that the Wi-Fi part still works I assume the PCI-e slot is still on) the card and not attempt any communication with it, and that seems to do the trick and the card isn't bricked when the OS detects all USB devices, and it can thus load the correct firmware and finally make the device functional.

Try to tinker with the USB options of your BIOS and/or try to disable the mini PCI-Express slot of the machine, in the worst case scenario that may make the Wi-Fi part unusable but you'll at least keep the Bluetooth.

Or better and easier solution : stay away from this card (and from all Broadcom cards - they all seem to have very poor Linux support also which is completely unacceptable for network hardware) and buy other stuff - Atheros based cards are very good for the Wi-Fi, not sure if they make Bluetooth modules though.