# bluetooth windows 8.1 stops working - unknown USB Device

Tags: drivers, windows-8.1, bluetooth

I just bought a brand new Dell XPS Windows 8.1 laptop. I used the Bluetooth for the first time today with a Microsoft Mouse. I had no problems until I restarted my computer and came back to it. Now my Bluetooth is no longer visible in Device Manager. I have an Unknown USB Device (Device Descriptor Request Failed) in its place. I went to Dell, downloaded the latest drivers from my model (which is the same drivers that were already installed), and it does not detect them or turn the Bluetooth back on. I found this:

[Bluetooth disappeared. Unknown USB device appeared](https://superuser.com/questions/360842/bluetooth-disappeared-unknown-usb-device-appeared)

This is exactly what is happening. Reinstalling the driver doesn't work. Should I install Linux just to fix this problem?

Thanks,
Jonathan

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After spending four hours installing, uninstalling drivers, messing with settings and pretty much trying out the same old methods four hundred message boards have posted, I finally got it to work.  I updated the bios drivers (which Dell said I didn't need to). They were only a month newer than the computer itself.  I believe it reset something that perhaps dual booting into another operating system resets.  Who knows?  It is working for now.  Hopefully it will stay that way.