# Unknown USB Device - Bluetooth Dongle

Tags: usb, drivers, windows-10, bluetooth

I have a generic bluetooth dongle that I got several years ago. I tried to use it today on my Windows 10 PC and I got an error saying it wasn't able to install the drivers.

The device manager says it cannot find the device descriptor.
[image: Screenshot of USB error]

I've tried different USB ports (USB 2 and USB 3) with the same result. I ran SFC which returned no issues. I have also updated the drivers for my motherboard with the same result when I plug the dongle in. On a whim I even tried it in another Windows 10 PC where it worked immediately.

So to summarize:

- Worked in previous versions of Windows (XP and 7)
- Works on other Windows 10 PCs
- Works in Ubuntu and OSX
- Totally generic, no manufacturer or model number on the casing

This [question](https://superuser.com/questions/360842/bluetooth-disappeared-unknown-usb-device-appeared) appears similar but provides no actual solution. I am completely baffled, any suggestions?

**EDIT**

To throw another spanner in the works, I just plugged it into the USB port the side of my screen and it worked immediately. I would still like to know the reasons why it still won't work in the original ports.

Comment: I know possible ways to fix this. Do the "hidden devices tweak" then also "show hidden devices" in the device manager. Remove the ghosted mess, especially any "unknown devices" because unknowns can re-find a device when it is plugged again into that particular port, and remain unknown, instead of re-checked for drivers

Answer (score 1):

If the original port itself is fine, then the issue could be a driver conflict with that particular port.
Code 43 results when the hardware cannot communicate well with each other through that port Group due to device driver failure or device hardware failure.

Other ports work since the device driver is being reconfigured through clean ports from scratch. Microsoft has to get their acts together, to see if they can prevent such buggy situations.

It is  good practice to not always swap ports, especially printer, USB wlan, Bluetooth dongles & EXT HDD. Using a dedicated port for these devices can avoid such issues.
A driver conflict happened when I swapped my 8 year old Bluetooth Dongle with that of my WLAN Dongle. At that time, I had to Uninstall every device under the Universal Serial Bus controllers in Device Manager to resolve the Code 43 problem.

I often come across these type of issues. I work as a Tech Support Specialist for an MNC.  More often Than not, issues occur on a Tuesday or a Wednesday. That's the time Microsoft used to push updates.
Many times a simple restart of the system and or reconnecting the USB device fixes the problem.

I faced a similar 'Device descriptor request failed - Code 43'  issue 2 days ago with one of my USB Devices. But for a different reason and a different device. It was with my 8GB Strontium USB Drive.
There were some windows updates happening in the background, which I was not aware, and I had Hibernated my system after use. I disconnected the USB device from the computer after the system Hibernated.

The next day I resumed the system from hibernation and tried to access the USB drive, after Reconnecting it, It was not getting detected in windows. I restarted the system, Windows then was Configuring updates. Even after the system restarted after configuring the updates, the USB device was not getting detected. Checked in device manager and found Unknown Device (Device Descriptor 
Request Failed) Code 43.

However, this time , by just uninstalling the respective device from the device Manager and scanning for HW changes resolved the problem.

Hope this answers your query.